# Deploying a MERN stack application to CPANEL. Apparently no able to connect to any servers in MongoDB Atlas cluster

Tags: node.js, mongodb, deployment, cpanel

I am trying, for the first time ever, to deploy the backend of my application to CPANEL. I have followed different tutorials but I'm continuously getting the error: 503 Service Unavailable The server is temporarily busy, try again later!

There might be a list of things I am doing wrong, but all I can get is an error when I try to run the npm packages saying "Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted.

In mongoDB, Network Access, I have added my IP Address (and even allowed access from any IP address, 0.0.0.0/0) but I still get this message.

Other details that might be useful to know if anyone is able to help me:

- Node version in CPANEL and local machine are the same (16.15.0)
- Env variables are set
- .htaccess file is populated with (I believe) the appropiate code.

Thanks for any advice!